# Converting a 1D list into a 2D list with a given row length in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, sorting

Is there an easy way to convert a 1D list into a 2D list with a given row length?

Suppose I have a list like this:

```
myList =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I want to convert the above list into a 3 x 3 table like below:

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I know I can accomplish this by creating a new 2D list called `myList2` and inserting the element into `MyList2` using 2 nested for loops. Like `MyList2[x][y] = myList[i] i++`

I think there should be a better way to do it (without using external libraries or modules)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with slice:

```
>>> myList =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> n = 3
>>> [myList[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(myList), n)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```